# Is there a way to express read/write/read-write attributes of records in types?

Tags: haskell

Suppose you have the following product type:

```hs
data D = D { getA :: Int, getB :: Char, getC :: [Double] }
```

and suppose you have a function:

```hs
f :: D -> D
```

which only reads the `getA` field, but modifies `getB` and `getC`.

Is there a convenient way to express this in the type of `f`?

Comment: What do you mean by `-> .... ->`? If these are other `D` arguments that are somehow merged into the result, then it's not clear what “modifies” means. If they're just other arguments that aren't relevant here, you might as well omit them from the question entirely.

Comment: Anyways, I doubt it's really worth trying to express this property through the type system. In Coq, maybe, but not in Haskell.

Comment: Good point. I wanted to express the fact that `f` might take another parameters. Let me edit the question.

Comment: I also share your doubts about the usefulness of expressing this in the type-system. A possible way of expressing is through type-classes, but the overhead might offset any possible benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, let's consider an example:

```
f :: D -> D
f d = d { getC = map (+ fromIntegral (getA d)) (getC d) }
```

Clearly, as soon as you have a concrete type like `D -> D`, all guarantees are off: this function could conceivably be doing *anything* with its argument.

If you want to prevent that, you need to replace the concrete `D` with an abstract one, like

```
f :: d -> d
```

But of course then the implementation wouldn't work anymore, because on `d` there's *nothing* you can do.

```
   • Couldn't match expected type ‘d’ with actual type ‘D’
      ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          f :: forall d. d -> d
```

To re-enable just those particular operation you want, you can pass them in as arguments. So, what is a “read-operation or modify-operation parameter”?
Enter [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). Let's first rewrite all the original example using them:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data D = D { _getA :: Int, _getB :: Char, _getC :: [Double] }
makeLenses ''D

f :: D -> D
f d = d & getC %~ map (+ fromIntegral (d^.getA))
```

Now, this can be readily generalised / strengthified, by making `d` abstract but passing the necessary access operations as arguments:

```
type AGetter' s a = Getting a s a   -- for some reason this isn't defined
                                    -- in the `lens` library

f' :: AGetter' d Int -> ASetter' d [Double] -> d -> d
f' getInt setDbls d = d & setDbls %~ map (+ fromIntegral (d^.getInt))
```

Which allows you to obtain the old behaviour by passing the `getA` and `getC` lenses:

```
f :: D -> D
f = f' getA getC
```

The reasons this works is that `lens` uses typeclass/universal-quantification type trickery to encode a subtype relationship: `getA` has type `Lens' D Int`, but `AGetter' D Int` is a supertype of that with reduced capability, thus guaranteeing that you really only read the focused element, nothing else.

---

Technical detail: you've noticed I wrote `ASetter'` and not `Setter'` or `ASetter`. What this means:

- The `AnOᴘᴛɪᴄ` versions of `Oᴘᴛɪᴄ`s are their *rank-0 correspondents*. So e.g. `ALens` can *only* be used as a lens, not as e.g. a getter, whereas `Lens` can be used as a getter or setter or traversal or fold.
  It is considered good style to restrict function arguments to the concrete `AnOᴘᴛɪᴄ` version, because that means the compiler doesn't actually have to juggle around with rank-2 types. (The type of a `Lens` itself is merely rank-1 polymorphic, but passing it as an argument would make the accepting function rank-2 polymorphic.)
- The `Oᴘᴛɪᴄ'` version of `Oᴘᴛɪᴄ`s are the *non-type-changing* variants. In principle, an e.g. setter could also change the type of a field it focuses on – e.g. when you change the `snd` type of a `(Bool, Char)` tuple to `String`, that would be a `Setter (Bool,Char) (Bool,String) Char String`, but if you just change the second field to another `Char`, it's simply a `Setter' (Bool,Char) Char` (which is actually [a synonym](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#t:ASetter-39-) for a type-changing setter which happens to change to the same type).

Answer (score 2):

If you're lens-phobic like me you could get a satisfying solution using only parametricity and a rank 2 type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

import Data.Char (toLower)

-- The goal of the question: a type that expresses
-- - Reading an Int
-- - Modifying a Char
-- - Modifying a [Double]
-- Parametricity guarantees your can't do anything else with that t
type YourParticularType = forall t .
     (t -> Int)
  -> ((Char -> Char) -> t -> t)
  -> (([Double] -> [Double]) -> t -> t)
  -> (t -> t)

-- One example of something in that type.
-- No mention of D here, so the user can be sure it won't do
-- anything silly.
f_parametric :: YourParticularType
f_parametric getInt modifyChar modifyDoubles t =
    modifyDoubles (fromIntegral (getInt t) :)
  . modifyChar toLower
  $ t

data D = D
  { getA :: Int
  , getB :: Char
  , getC :: [Double]
  } deriving (Show)

modifyB :: (Char -> Char) -> D -> D
modifyB f d = d { getB = f (getB d) }

modifyC :: ([Double] -> [Double]) -> D -> D
modifyC f d = d { getC = f (getC d) }

-- Shows that D is of suitable form to match YourParticularType
run_f_at_d :: YourParticularType -> D -> D
run_f_at_d f = f getA modifyB modifyC

d1 :: D
d1 = D 42 'Z' [3.14, 1.41]

d2 :: D
d2 = run_f_at_d f_parametric d1
```

Comment: very interesting, thank you for this. if we *can pretend* it quacks like a D and walks like a D...  also I wonder if it can be related to abstract data types somehow. googling "abstract data types higher rank polymorphism" does bring up something...

Comment: The relation to abstract data types is there. Look into Church encoding. `YourParticularType` is a (very mangled, indirect) Church encoding of the free monad over `T a = A (Int -> a) | B (Char -> Char) a | C ([Double] -> [Double]) a`. This suggests a kind of dual way of approaching the original question: give an ADT that represents queries and updates, then an interpreter for it that uses the `D` type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to look at this, if you just want a function that 'modifies' `D` the it would have a type of `f :: D -> D`. See here for an example:

```hs
f :: D -> D
f (D a b c) = D a (modifyB a b) (modifyC a c)
  where modifyB = undefined -- function of type Int -> Char -> Char
        modifyC = undefined -- function of type Int -> [Double] -> [Double]
```

Another way is to take two functions as arguments to `f`, one of type `Int -> Char -> Char` and one of type `Int -> [Double] -> [Double]`. Here is an example:

```hs
f :: (Int -> Char -> Char)
   -> (Int -> [Double] -> [Double])
   -> D
   -> D
f modifyB modifyC (D a b c) = D a (modifyB a b) (modifyC a c)
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that the problem with this answer is that `f` could still do anything to the fields of `D` :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `D` is too specific. The more you know about a type, the more you can do with a value of it. The reverse is true as well: the *less* you know, the less you can do with it. The extreme example is `id`:

```
id :: a -> a
```

Because you know *nothing* about `a`, the only thing you can do with an input of type `a` is return it as-is.

Start by making `D` less specific:

```
data D' a b c = D' { getA :: a, getB :: b, getC :: c }
```

Now, you can define `f' :: D' a Char [Double] -> D' a Char [Double]`, which can modify `getB` and `getC` in various ways, but can do *nothing* except reuse `getA` in the output.

You can further restrict what `f'` can do to the two fields by passing the functions that do the work as arguments, similar to what Jack Higgins suggested:

```
f' :: (b -> b) -> (c -> c) -> D' a b c -> D' a b c
```

Now `f'` has only one real implementation:

```
f' f g (D' x y z) = D' x (f y) (g z)
```

---

Taking one more step, `D'` is an example of a *trifunctor*, which is a straightforward (though not predefined or commonly used) extension of a functor.

```
class Trifunctor (p :: * -> * -> * -> *) where
    trimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (e -> f) -> p a c e -> p b d f


instance Trifunctor D' where
    trimap f g h (D' x y z) = D' (f x) (g y) (h z)
```

Then

```
f' :: (b -> b) -> (c -> c) -> D' a b c -> D' a b c
f' bf cf = trimap id bf cf
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete solution because it builds on the [`HasField`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html#t:HasField) typeclass from [`GHC.Records`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html) which ([so far)](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0158-record-set-field.rst) only provides getters, not setters. We can write the following function, that explicitly lists the required fields as constraints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeApplications, FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.Records
import GHC.TypeLits

f :: HasField "getA" r Int => r -> r
f r = let _ = getField @"getA" r 
       in undefined -- do some stuff
```

Using typeclasses in this way lets us avoid potential problems with clients accidentally passing the wrong lenses as parameters.

We might also want to preserve "nominal" typing: to forbid clients from mistakenly passing records that are not of type `D` but have—by mere chance—compatible fields. Record types like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

data Z = Z { getA :: Int, getB :: Char, getC :: [Double] } deriving Show
```

We need to define this auxiliary module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Opaque(Opaque(..)) where

import Data.Type.Equality ((:~:)(Refl))    

newtype HiddenEq a b = HiddenEq (a :~: b)

-- fix concrete a, be polymorphic over b
class Opaque a b where
    opaque :: HiddenEq a b

-- all types have this instance!
instance Opaque a a where
    opaque = HiddenEq Refl
```

`Opaque a b` says that `a` is actually equal to `b`, but it doesn't let you access the evidence. Now we can write a function like this:

```
f' :: (Opaque D r, HasField "getA" r Int) => r -> r
f' r = let _ = getField @"getA" r 
        -- _ = getField @"getB" -- we know r is D, but we can't touch the "getB" field
        in undefined
```

putting `f` and `f'` to use:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ f (D 3 'c' [1.0]) -- compiles
    print $ f (Z 3 'c' [1.0]) -- compiles
    print $ f' (D 3 'c' [1.0]) -- compiles
    print $ f' (Z 3 'c' [1.0]) -- doesn't compile
```